# Can Google Play Billing Library be used on Inventor 2?

Tags: android, app-inventor, google-play-billing

Can Google Play Billing Library be used on Inventor 2?

i want know it

example:

dependencies {
val billing_version = "4.0.0"

```
implementation("com.android.billingclient:billing:$billing_version")
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own extension or use this extension https://puravidaapps.com/billing.php

How to write your own extension see here http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/extensions.html

Comment: Does this require additional payment to the author?

Comment: if you want to use the already available extension then yes... feel free to write your own extension and provide it for free to the community...